# Different animation duration for subviews of an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have the following code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

            mainPage.frame=CGRectMake(0, -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);

        } completion:nil];
```

Is there any way to control the animation duration of the subviews of mainPage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIView:animateKeyframesWithDuration` then use `UIView:addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime` to set its start time and duration

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.32 relativeDuration:0.68 animations:^{
        view.frame = frame;
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
        subview.frame = frame2;
    }];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subviews to animate with a different duration then you'll need to animate each of them separately. You can loop through the mainPage.subviews array and issue an `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` call to each subview in turn, each with a different duration.